# Why load regulation formula is different from percentage decrease formula?

Tags: voltage-regulator

The load regulation formula is
$$\frac{V_{NL}-V_{FL}}{V_{FL}}\times100\%$$

Why don't we use the percentage decrease formula?
$$\frac{V_{NL}-V_{FL}}{V_{NL}}\times100\%$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For load regulation, the reference is the voltage at full load. Removing the load causes the voltage to deviate from the desired value.

For percentage decrease (error) the reference is the original value. THe decrease is the deviation from the desired value.

The difference between the two is what is considered the desired value.